# C# using Powershell.AddParameter with two conditions

Tags: c#, powershell

I'd like to call a PowerShell script in c#.  In Terminal the command would look like

```
get-mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails "EquipmentMailbox","RoomMailbox"
```

I can get it to run if I just use one Recipient type, for example "RoomMailbox", this works fine.

```
ps.AddCommand("Get-Mailbox");
ps.AddParameter("RecipientTypeDetails" , "RoomMailbox");
```

but i dont know how to add EquipmentMailbox to the parameter conditions, so to show both types.

```
ps.AddCommand("Get-Mailbox");
ps.AddParameter("RecipientTypeDetails" , "RoomMailbox,EquipmentMailboxes");
```

Thanks!

Comment: `.AddParameter("RecipientTypeDetails", new string[] { "RoomMailbox", "EquipmentMailboxes" });` should work

Comment: THis looks a lot simpler than creating a PS script.  Any advantage to using the process below compared to this one liner?  thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an array to bind both arguments to the `RecipientTypeDetails` parameter. A simple way to test how arguments are bound is to define a simple PowerShell script:

```
public static Collection<PSObject> Run()
{
    using PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create()
        .AddScript(@"
            [cmdletbinding()]
            param($RecipientTypeDetails)

            $PSBoundParameters
        ")
        .AddParameter(
            "RecipientTypeDetails",
            new string[] { "RoomMailbox", "EquipmentMailbox" });

    return ps.Invoke();
}
```

Alternatively, if the cmdlet has many parameters, you might find easier by using [`AddParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addparameters?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) instead:

```
public static Collection<PSObject> Run()
{
    using PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create()
        .AddScript(@"
            [cmdletbinding()]
            param($foo, $bar, $baz)

            $PSBoundParameters
        ")
        .AddParameters(new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "foo", new string[] { "RoomMailbox", "EquipmentMailbox" } },
            { "bar", "hello" },
            { "baz", "world" }
        });

    return ps.Invoke();
}
```